# Logs not shown in eclipse console

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I'm new to Log4J and I'm trying to show my application log on eclispe console.

This is my log4j properties file:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout
# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

And this is my class:

```
public class MyWorker {

Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(MyWorker.class);


public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyWorker worker = ew MyWorker();
    worker.execute();
}

private void execute() {
    logger.debug("Starting");
    logger.info("Starting");
}   
}
```

but using this approach nothing is shown in eclipse console.

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about log4j? There is no `LogFactory` or `Log` class in log4j.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean org.apache.commons.logging.logfactory and log interface?

I tested your code and got a result in eclipse console:

`07.07.2015 12:46:55 temp.LogTest execute`
`INFO: Starting`

Maybe the property-file is not found?